# answer terminal query and log in ssh automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I get no response running

```
workssh() { sshpass -p "password" ssh user@$1 ;}
```

It was erroring out due to the host being unknown:

```
cchilders: [master]$ ssh user@host
The authenticity of host 'host (10.10.10.10)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'host, 10.10.10.10' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@host's password: 
Last login: Tue Mar 15 11:16:03 2016 from 10.55.55.55
```

If I log in by hand once and say yes, the function `workssh` now works. How can I make this command work the first time even iworkssh() { sshpass -p "password" ssh user@$1 ;}f host is unknown? thank you

Comment: In theory, this is a feature. You shouldn't be sending your password to a remote host whose identity you haven't yet confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

First of: what @chepner said in the comments; I *don't* recommend doing this for security reasons. But here's your answer, anyway:

```
workssh() { if $(grep -vq $1 ~/.ssh/known_hosts); then ssh-keyscan $1 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts; fi ; sshpass -p "password" ssh user@$1 ;}
```

Notes: for this to work you will need to have **HashKnownHosts** set to **no** in **man ssh_config**, which, in itself, is considered a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can go down the hole as the other answer propose, but if you want to be insecure, there are more simple ways to do that:

```
workssh() { sshpass -p "password" ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$1 ;}
```

which will do basically the same. But once more, it is not recommended, because the host checking is the only mechanism protecting you from the Man In the Middle attack, as you have probably already noticed in your testing.

Comment: I see, if you passed the password before host check anyone can jump in and pretend to be that host. Is there any way for people to know you're doing that? or does it just open you up to random mitm attacks

Comment: Point of MiTM attack is that the users won't notice anything. The remote server can re-encode what you post him and be an transparent interface reading your passwords and everything you type/transfer. You can make it easier for user by providing SSHFP DNS records or provide pre-generated `known_hosts` file of your in-advance verified hosts.

Comment: ok the pregenerated known hosts is great. this script is an auto setup in python so I can make minor changes to machine setup if I need to reinstall, thank you

Comment: You can use `ssh-keyscan` as mentioned in the other answer, if you believe your local network and DNS where you will prepare it, or just create it "by hand" aggregating public host keys from all hosts you are interested in.